# How to use MacBook from my PC

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion

I have a PC with a big monitor and a 13" MacBook sitting on my desk. I have to do some development in PC environment and also some iOS development on MacBook.

Is there a way I could use my PC's monitor, mouse and keyboard with both PC and MacBook?

Basically, I want to be able to switch between PC's and MacBooks's desktops at will. Something like two virtual desktops: one showing what's going on on PC and the seconds one showing what's MacBook doing. All mouse movements and keystrokes should go to currently *active* desktop.

I do not want to purchase any additional hardware if possible.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) will let you do this for the mouse and keyboard part. My laptop connects as a client to the desktop, and I can then simply move the mouse pointer across to the laptop screen to control the laptop's mouse and keyboard input. It feels a lot like a regular two monitor setup, except obviously you can't drag apps between screens. It is cross platform - my laptop is Windows while my desktop is Ubuntu.

If you really want to control an OS X screen from your PC, then you want to go the remote desktop route. You can setup the VNC server for OS X without needing to install anything - just [follow these instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X#Mac_OS_X_10.4_or_10.5_-_Setup_as_Server).

Comment: As far as I can tell, Synergy will give me one keyboard and mouse for both computers but NOT one monitor. This is not what I want. I need everything on one monitor (so I can tuck MacBook somewhere but still be able to use it for iOS development).

Comment: Okay. Thought I'd suggest it as for me at least, being able to see both displays at once is preferable. In your case, you'd want to install one of the various free virtual desktop servers on your MacBook, and then connect to it from your desktop. VNC is popular and included with OS X.